# Google Apps Script takes very long (or doesn't run at all)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a simple script that checks the cell contents for how many dashes it contains and changes the cell colour accordingly. The function trigger is set to onEdit().

For some reason I don't know, this script takes at least a few seconds to run, if it even runs at all.
I would like to ask for help to explain why this takes very long to execute.
Thank you in advance.

```
function checkSix() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var currentCell = sheet.getCurrentCell();
var contents = currentCell.getValue();

var amt = contents.replace(/[^-]/g, "").length;
if(amt >= 6)
  currentCell.setBackground('red');
else if(amt == 5)
  currentCell.setBackground('yellow');
else
  currentCell.setBackground('white');  
}
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your situation, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought that your script is correct. When I tested it, the process time was about 1 second. Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue, can you test the following modification?

#### Modification points:

1. In your script, the if statement of the multiple conditional branches is used.

   - From [the benchmark](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/cef47530a58f2d8692cdb1a9d257907b), when the ternary operator is used, a process cost can be reduced a little.
2. Your function of `checkSix()` is executed by OnEdit trigger of `onEdit`.

   - From [the benchmark](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/4892c97df7ac0504ffd715c2dd6cd546), when the event object is used, a process cost can be reduced a little.
3. From `or doesn't run at all`, I thought that several users might use Google Spreadsheet.

   - In this case, I would like to propose to use LockService.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From your question, it supposes that in your situation, `checkSix` is called from `onEdit` as follows. Please be careful this. When the lock service is not used, the script becomes as follows.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  checkSix(e);
}

function checkSix(e) {
  var currentCell = e.range;
  var amt = e.range.getValue().replace(/[^-]/g, "").length;
  currentCell.setBackground(amt >= 6 ? 'red' : amt == 5 ? 'yellow' : 'white');
}
```

When the lock service is used, the script becomes as follows.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  checkSix(e);
}

function checkSix(e) {
  var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
  if (lock.tryLock(10000)) {
    try {
      var currentCell = e.range;
      var amt = e.range.getValue().replace(/[^-]/g, "").length;
      currentCell.setBackground(amt >= 6 ? 'red' : amt == 5 ? 'yellow' : 'white');
    } catch(er) {
      throw new Error(er);
    } finally {
      lock.releaseLock();
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- In this answer, it supposes that your script is only the script shown in your question. If you run other functions when `onEdit` is run, my proposal might not be useful. Please be careful this.
- If above modification was not the direct solution of your issue, as a test case, I would like to propose to try to create new Spreadsheet and test it again.

#### References:

- [Benchmark: Conditional Branch using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/cef47530a58f2d8692cdb1a9d257907b)
- [Benchmark: Event Objects for Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/4892c97df7ac0504ffd715c2dd6cd546)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: I tried to use the modified script (without lock service) and it runs well enough, although it still takes a few seconds to run. I'm guessing this might be due to my internet connection?

As for the lock service, I do not think it is necessary since only 2 people (including me) are able to edit said spreadsheet.

Comment: @Shironats Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. At Google Apps Script, the process time is not the same every run. I thought that this might be also affected. For example, as other method, when you create new Spreadsheet and test the modified script again, what result will you obtain? About the lock service, I couldn't understand about your actual situation. So I proposed 2 patterns.

Comment: I tried creating a new spreadsheet and running the exact same script took around 1 second, same as your answer. However, in the spreadsheet in question, it always takes at least several seconds, even though the spreadsheet only has one sheet and no other scripts running on it.

Comment: @Shironats Thank you for replying. Although, unfortunately, I'm not sure about your actual Spreadsheet, in my experience, there is the case that when new Spreadsheet is created, the issue was resolved. So I proposed it. In that case, I thought that the issue might be due to the internal issue. So when you can create new Spreadsheet and use it, I would like to propose to do it. I deeply apologize that I cannot directly tell the clear reason of the issue. This is due to my poor skill.

Comment: No worries, thank you very much for the help. I really appreciate the explanation.

Comment: @Shironats Thank you for replying. In the current stage, to create new Spreadsheet might be one of several methods for resolving the current issue. So, I added it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkSix(e) {
const sh = e.range.getSheet();
if(sh.getName() == 'Your Sheet Name' && e.value ) {
  let contents = e.value;
  let l = contents.replace(/[^-]/g,'').length;
  if(l>=6) {
    e.range.setBackground('red');
  }else if(l==5) {
    e.range.setBackground('yellow');
  } else {
    e.range.setBackground('while');
  }
  
}
```

Since you changed the name you will require an installable onEdit trigger. Or call it from onEdit(e) function.